# Find the inverse function of $ f(x) = 4 - x^2$,$ x\geq 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the inverse function of f 
$$
f(x) = 4 - x^2, x\geq 0
$$
I know that Power Functions raised to the second power are not one to one; however, since the domain for this function is $[0,\infty)$, it is. Yet, I am still a little confused as to how to properly find the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow (-\infty,4]$, $f(x)=4-x^2$. Then, $f$ is bijective, ok?

Then, $f$ is invertible, i.e., $\exists f^{-1}: (-\infty,4]\rightarrow [0,+\infty)$, $x=f^{-1}(y)$:
$$ y=4-x^2 \Rightarrow y=4-(f^{-1}(y))^2,$$
then
$$f^{-1}(y)=\sqrt{4-y}. $$

Conclusion: $f^{-1}: (-\infty,4]\rightarrow [0,+\infty)$, $f^{-1}(y)=\sqrt{4-y}$ is the inverse of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find some $y$ so that $f(y)=x$.  So, you need to solve
$$
x=4-y^2.
$$

Comment: I could transfer the "y" to the left; yet that still would lead me to square root both sides. Thus, I would get + or - y = the square root of 4-x for the answer. Is that right? If so why mathematically am I allowed to that?